# Yii2 cannot send email in yii2

Tags: email, yii2

I'm using yii2 and I'm totally new to this can someone help me with sending emails in this framework I'm using swiftmailer and have set the configurations as:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the transport correctly

In this example i suppose you use gmail,  if this is not true you need change the values with your values.

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'yourName@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'yourPassword',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I did that, now I keep getting an error :      Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "+OK <15176.1431402822@mail511.opentransfer.com>
"

Comment: This because you must set the correct configuration for your mail transport.

Comment: Is there a way to get the label ex options here in yii2, I have managed to get it done still is there some other option my code is:                                   <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->label('Email'. Html::tag('span', '*',['class'=>'text-danger']))
               ->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Enter your email')) ?>                                                                                                                           is there some other possible and simple way

Comment: I just did it some other way now.. I used the template option, like this:                
       <?= $form->field($model, 'name',[
          'template' => "{label}\n<span class='text-danger'>*</span>\n{input}\n{error}"])
          ->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'Name')) ?>                                         N thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport'=>false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
    ],
```

Add these lines to config/main.php.
Make a view for your mail body and give path to that view in below function
and use that code you want to send the mail

```
$check=Yii::$app->mailer->compose('../../frontend/views/mail',  ['data'=> 'Mail data'])
        ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('testsent@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('check sending mail')
        ->send();
    var_dump($check);
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your `common->config->main-local.php` file under components  section:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'your@email.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your port this was my problem when i worked with mailer in yii2